# Doctrine 2.2 ORM: find extended entity

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm

How should I annotate inheritance to be able to find a subclass?

My current annotations:

```php
<?php
// Product.php
namespace Entity;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="products")
 **/
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
}


<?php
namespace Entity;
// Coffee.php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Coffee extends Product
{
    protected $taste;    
}
```

It works like a charm when I persist new entities, but fail to fetch an existent entity by Id

```php
$entityManager->find('Entity\\Coffee', 1)
```

with error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause'

I cannot use [MappedSuperclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) for Products.

---

**UPDATE:**

`Product::taste` is not a database column. It is a POPO field. I must confuse myself with Doctrine ORM inheritance, which aims to extend model to persist extra data for extended entities. In my case the child class has no extra columns, but rather defines different behaviour of the base class. Furthermore, both are mutually interchangeable, so I expect

```php
$coffee = new Entity\Coffee();
$entityManager->persist($coffee);
$entityManager->flush();

/* @var Entity\Product $product */
$product = $entityManager->find('Entity\\Product', $coffee->getId());

/* @var Entity\Coffee $coffee */
$coffee = $entityManager->find('Entity\\Coffee', $product->getId());
```

It seems I don't really need ORM inheritance, but just hydration of data from `products` table into either base or child objects. Not sure if it possible though.

Comment: just add the protected id with the correct annotation to the child class... without the annotation doctrine cant call the find method on the repository.

Comment: Could Single Table Inheritance work for you? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: @Rufinus Thanks, but it doesn't help. AFAIK AnnotationDriver get annotations from parent classes, and my problem lies in metadata factory. It creates 1 alias 't0' for child class and uses it in `where` clause, then create another alias 't1' and use in in `from` clause.

Comment: @bspellmeyer It is a single table. I tried to add `@InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")` explicitly without any effect though. Not sure if Discriminators do the trick, but I'd like to avoid meaningless columns in database if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply InheritanceType, DiscriminatorMap, and DiscriminatorColumn on the superclass to correctly map the inheritance relationship.  It will add exactly one extra column to the table (the one you specify in DiscriminatorColumn).

Comment: I have updated my question to avoid further confusion. 
If I use `@DiscriminatorMap({"anything" = "Product", "anything" = "Coffee"})` I cannot persist Products, and if I use `@DiscriminatorMap({"product" = "Product", "coffee" = "Coffee"})` it returns `Coffee` object when I try to get `$entityManager->find('Entity\\Product', $coffee->getId());`

Comment: Based on your update, I'm confused about what you're really trying to do.  But either way, just use all three discriminators, and you'll get what you want, I think.

Comment: Yes, I must admit it is confusing. The problem with discriminators is the value in the discriminator column defines class of the resulting object.

Comment: How is that a problem?  Doctrine needs to know if row #123 in the table should be hydrated as Product of Coffee.  If there wasn't a discriminator column, Doctrine wouldn't be able to consistently tell the difference.

Comment: I need to control it from application rather than from database. Doctrine knows both Entity name and Id from `$entityManager->find(name, id)` which should be enough to fetch a row and hydrate it into requested class. The problem with discriminators that I don't control it runtime. Since object persisted as `Coffee` it cannot be hydrated into `Product`.

The last code example in the question is not working with discriminators. `$product` is an instance of `Coffee` there, which is not what I expect.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, Coffee and Product are indistinguishable on the database level.  You should update your question with more detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve (include the table definition, at least).  It sounds to me like inheritance (as far as doctrine) is concerned is probably not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary workaround I have found so far is to use single table inheritance advised by @bspellmeyer and @timdev with [dynamic mapping](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html?highlight=events#load-classmetadata-event):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

class ProductEntityListener
{
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $metadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        if (in_array($metadata->getName(), [
            'Entity\Coffee',
            'Entity\Product'
        ])) {
            $metadata->setInheritanceType(ClassMetadata::INHERITANCE_TYPE_SINGLE_TABLE);
            $metadata->setDiscriminatorColumn(['name' => 'discr', 'type' => 'string', 'length' => 3]);
            $metadata->addDiscriminatorMapClass('all', $metadata->getName());
            $metadata->subClasses = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Although it does the job I don't mark it as a correct answer because it still requires an extra meaningless column `discr` which contains 'all' for all rows and is is rather a hack. I wonder if there is a proper solution to extend Entity class without extending ORM model.

Comment: The _dynamic mapping_ link in this post is dead. The new link is https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event